gradle sync failed after updating the android studio
I have an android project and I updated my android studio to jellyfish yesterday, since then I can't sync my project, I get the following error, I searched in the stack overflow and watched some videos on youtube but none of them could help me. I hope you guys can help me to fix this. my project worked fine before updating the android studio. I'm kind of new here and I don't know if I should post the whole error here so I'm sorry if I did something wrong.
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A build operation failed.
    There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@2ae6a159 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
There was a failure while populating the build operation queue: Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@2ae6a159 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
Could not isolate parameters com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@2ae6a159 of artifact transform D8BackportedMethodsGenerator
Could not isolate value com.android.build.gradle.internal.utils.D8BackportedMethodsGenerator$Parameters_Decorated@2ae6a159 of type D8BackportedMethodsGenerator.Parameters
Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.



==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Failed to stop service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService_d633e49b-6b9e-4a55-badd-33382715f353'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.services.internal.ServiceLifecycleException: Failed to stop service 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService_d633e49b-6b9e-4a55-badd-33382715f353'.
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.lambda$maybeStop$1(RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.ifSuccessful(Try.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.maybeStop(RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.java:165)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.lambda$discardAll$8(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:294)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.ExecutionResult.forEach(ExecutionResult.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.lambda$discardAll$9(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:290)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.withRegistrations(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.discardAll(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:287)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.access$100(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.DefaultBuildServicesRegistry$ServiceCleanupListener.buildFinished(DefaultBuildServicesRegistry.java:389)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:472)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:454)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:443)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:431)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:268)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:170)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:381)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:272)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy38.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$finishBuild$11(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.ExecutionResult.maybeFailing(ExecutionResult.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$finishBuild$12(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransitionWithFailures(StateTransitionController.java:241)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$13(StateTransitionController.java:232)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.finishBuild(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeFinishExecutor.finishBuildTree(DefaultBuildTreeFinishExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor$1.call(OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor$1.call(OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor.finishBuildTree(OperationFiringBuildTreeFinishExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$7(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:82)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:140)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.execute(InitDeprecationLoggingActionExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.InitProblems.execute(InitProblems.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl.reportRemainingIssues(SyncIssueReporterImpl.kt:72)
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0

    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl.access$reportRemainingIssues(SyncIssueReporterImpl.kt:39)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl$GlobalSyncIssueService.close(SyncIssueReporterImpl.kt:157)
    at org.gradle.api.services.internal.RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.lambda$maybeStop$1(RegisteredBuildServiceProvider.java:168)
    ... 133 more

==============================================================================

I want my project to sync successfully

@Robert
There was something wrong with my sdk, I deleted and redownload it and it worked, thank you bro you're a life saver

@Robert
you can promote your comment to an answer

The error message Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0 indicates that something is wrong with the installed build tools for API version 34.0.0.
You should open SDK Manager and check if on the "SDK Tools" tab the entry "Android SDK Build tools" the entry 34.0.0 is installed (make sure "Show Package Details" check box is enabled).
If this version is already installed try to uninstall and reinstall it.

